# Is it legal to set an input with type=number to be blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have `<input id="inpID" type="number" min="1" max="5" value="3"></input>`

would this code be legal:

`$("#inpID").val('');`

and does it work in practice in different environments/browsers?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cae9xs4x/

Comment: `does it work?`  Sounds like you didn't even try it

Comment: I tried it with my environment, but there are a lot of different browsers, and versions of browsers. Perhaps other environment factors as well. But I have edited the question to be more clear on this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)

`If the element is mutable, the user agent should allow the user to change the number represented by its value, as obtained from applying the rules for parsing floating-point number values to it. User agents must not allow the user to set the value to a non-empty string that is not a valid floating-point number.`

My read on that is that yes, it is okay to use an empty string.