# Input with type=number but add alphabetical suffix

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have `<input type="number"></input>`. I like the fact that it has `type="number"` since I want numeric input from the user. I would rather not change its type away from number. However, I would like to display the units after the number. So I want the input to read "5 px" if the unit is in pixels. I want the user to be able to edit the 5 part, but not the px part. The solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2913366/3470632) will not work unless I do more gimmicks and make it hackier, because the "px" would come after the up/down arrows in chrome. These are the arrows I'm talking about![example of arrows][1]

On my environment in chrome, you can just put alphabetical characters in the `<input ...>`, but this is [technically not legal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30769612/3470632)

I need a solution that works on firefox, chrome, safari, and IE9.

Comment: will "px" be the only unit you want to display or the user can select which unit he/she wants to display?

Comment: I will only be using "px". Bonus points for a more general solution though ;)

Comment: If using bootstrap, here is the [solution](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using following code:
HTML:

```
 <div class="size-input-wrapper">
    <label for="inputValidation">Enter size:</label>
    <input type="number" id="inputValidation" placeholder="size"/>
    <span class="pxSpan">px</span>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.size-input-wrapper {
    max-width: 208px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#inputValidation {
    padding-right: 35px;
}
.pxSpan {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzmrwtxx/)

Alternatively, you can use bootstrap for easier implementation. Check this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g8shvarw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making it a bit wider and floating a `<span>px</span>` on top of the `<input>`. With a bit of CSS it will look like it is part of the input content.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw it out there about how I was going to approach this before making this question. I was going to make an additional, identical `<input>` except not make it `type="number"` and make it `position: absolute`. That way it would stack directly under the actual `<input ...>`. I would then set its value to be "  px" putting a space for every digit in the other input. As long as you use a monospaced font, the 'px' should be placed correctly. Browsers may end up overlapping it with arrows or something though, who knows.

Edit: I ended up just making an absolutely positioned, `<label>`, if you set the `for` property to be the id of your input, then when you click on the `<label>` it will focus the input and be ready for keypresses. Then you just change the css of the label to be `cursor: text` so that when you mouse over the label it has the right cursor. I tested this on IE9+, FF, Safari, and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

So how about this general solution.

Create an extra input,

```
<input type="number" />
<input type="text" readonly value="px" class="unit"/>
```

Now make the second input borderless as,

```
.unit{
border: none;
border-color: transparent;
width: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code

```
 <input type="number" />
<label id="label1">px</label>
```

We have consider Lable for FIX (px) value over here.

Please mark answer as right if helpful to you.